# create image from usb in windows?

Tags: windows, usb

how do I create an image from a usb stick in windows..  that I could then later write to a usb in rufus or whatever program.

also I want to make an image(from a usb stick), where the image  doesn't include the files(if that's possible), so it'd copy any boot record or partition, (I understand that info may be at the beginning of the disk anyway), and I could then add whatever files I want later.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the <Alt>-<V> [cheatmode](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#Power_keysCheat_modes) in Rufus to save an USB to an **uncompressed** VHD file. Then you can use that VHD in Rufus to re-create your flash drive. Oh, and you can also mount VHD files in Windows as virtual drives, if you want to access their content.

Note however that Rufus will save VHDs as **uncompressed** so it will create a file that is as big as your USB (which means, if you have a 16GB flash drive with only a few files on it, the VHD will be 16GB in size regardless).

Comment: that completely ignores my second paragraph

Comment: What you seek is not as easy as it seems. Especially, a GPT formatted drive will store information both at the beginning and end of the disk. It seems to me like you are looking for a very specialized tool for a specialized task... which means you may have to write your own, as general purpose tools will never achieve what you seek.